# Assembly.Load erro Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#

Eu estou tendo erro ao usar o `Assembly.Load(X);`. O caminho está certo, acho que está dando erro ao tentar carregar uma dependência do assembly. Mas eu acho estranho que no Visual Studio 2017 eu consigo importar o assembly para o meu projeto, sem nenhum erro. O `LoadFrom` e `LoadFile` não funciona, carrega o assembly atual do código. Estou usando o `.Net 3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o usuário do AppPool tem acesso à essa DLL e suas dependências.

Caso tenha,
verifique se o caminho da DLL especificado no método Load está correto.

Um erro possível, são as versões das DLLs e suas dependências, apesar da DLL requerida como dependência estar na pasta sua versão pode estar errada.

Outro ponto, pode ocorrer de quando a compilação estar sendo gerada, a DLL que você está esperando não está sendo copiada para a pasta da aplicação.